# AlertDialog in Android Api 29 used to dim the screen when it was shown, but in Api 34 instead it creates a shadow around the dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, android-alertdialog

AlertDialog in Android Api 29 used to dim the screen except for the dialog when it was shown, but in Api 34 instead it creates a shadow around the dialog.

The AlertDialog in android used to dim the screen like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KceTf.png)

but now it just adds shadow around the box like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UXtl.png)

I have tried the methods dialog.window?.setDimAmount()
I have tried github libraries

But they all dont work

Kotlin Code

```
    private fun showPopup(){
        val dialogBuilder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val dialog = dialogBuilder.create()
        val inflater = this.layoutInflater
        val dialogView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_sharing_number, null)
        dialog.setView(dialogView)
        dialog.show()
    }
```

Layout Code

```
<!-- popup_layout.xml -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background_alert_box"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_alert"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Why do I need to share my number?"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="For security reasons, we only use phone number as an authentication method. This counts for Students, Parents and Tutors. We will never charge via phone number"
        android:textColor="#7E8082"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="Close"
        android:background="@drawable/button_primary"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="12dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want it to Dim in all versions

Comment: Indeed. I first thought this is a feature of a different default behavior, but I think it is a bug. That is becasue calling dialog.window?.addFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND) and dialog.window?.setDimAmount(0.3f) has no influence anymore.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/270983047 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/289117017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an emulator rendering bug, now fixed as of January 2024. Now dialogs render the dimmed background correctly. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/289117017

Bug present in API 34 v8a emulator revision 11, emulator 33.1.23

Bug fixed in API 34 v8a emulator revision 12, emulator 33.1.24